# Track links with Event or Query strings with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, query-string

I am using Google Analytics and would like to see how users interact with my site, mainly what internal links they are clicking and from where.

One approach I've found is to add queries to my links like so `?ref=sidebar` or `?ref=featured`

Another approach is to use Event Tracking `_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Article', 'Click', 'Sidebar']);`

I am wondering: Is there any reason to use one approach over the other? I know Event Tracking can be used to capture Javascript events, which queries cannot. But most sites I've seen also uses Event Tracking on their links, instead of simply adding a query string. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query Strings make different unique urls.  So if you add query strings to your pages the pages report will show multiple entries for (basically) the same url depending on how people got there, e.g.:

```
subsite.html           
subsite.html?ref=sidebar 
subsite.html?ref=featured
```

each with it's own pageview count and other metrics.

Usually you do not want this. Event tracking is better since it does not blow up the url count (there might be be even better ways, especially if you upgrade to Universal Analytics and use custom dimensions).